# Converting A plain old object to value object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I think Im having a really noob moment, Im returning a remote object from coldfusion and I want to specify the object type. i.e Im getting an worker from coldfusion and I have a Value object Worker.

Heres what I have been trying

```
public function ResultHandler_GetWorker(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var result:ArrayCollection = ArrayCollection(event.result);
    var worker:WorkerVO = WorkerVO(result[0]);
    model.worker = worker;
}
```

`Result[0]` is an employee object. Its structure from debug looks like this.

workerAddress   "24b fake Ave"
workerCity  "Wellton"
workerCountry   "Ameriland" 
workerEmail "Afake@me.com"
workerFName "Foo"
workerHPhone    "435234"
workerID    1
workerImage null
workerIsAdmin   true
workerLName "Foo"
workerMPhone    "827271903" 
workerPassword  "password"
workerPosition  "Leader"
workerState ""
workerSuburb    "Birkenhead"
workerWPhone    null

my class looks like this:

```
public class WorkerVO
{       
    public var _workerAddress:String
    public var _workerCity:String
    public var _workerCountry:String    
    public var _workerEmail:String  
    public var _workerFName:String  
    public var _workerHPhone:String 
    public var _workerID:uint;  
    public var _workerImage:String
    public var _workerIsAdmin:Number;
    public var _workerLName:String
    public var _workerMPhone:String;
    public var _workerPassword:String;
    public var _workerPosition:String;
    public var _workerState:String;
    public var _workerSuburb:String;
    public var _workerWPhone:String;


    public function WorkerVO()
    {
    }

    //Getters & Setters 
}
```

*Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@114eeb251 to com.cavej03.sitesafe.vo.WorkerVO.*

Am I doing it completely wrong. Am I simply meant to make a function or constructor that accepts this object and maps its fields to a new WorkerVO

Comment: Yes to your final point.

Comment: I Think the better way to would be to map the results to the value object when they are returned via coldfusion, but I also have no clue how do to this.

Comment: @Marty is there a better way? can I make coldfusion return these objects as a value object automagically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a [RemoteClass](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a25) metadata tag. This tag tells your application which server-side VO a given client-side VO is mapped to.

Use it like this:

```
[RemoteClass(alias="path.to.WorkerVO")]  //this is the servers-side path
public class WorkerVO {
    ...
}
```

Furthermore from what you're showing it looks like the names of your properties don't match: the client-side one has prepended underscores while the server-side one doesn't.
The property names of the client-side VO and the server-side one should be exactly the same. For instance:

```
/* Java VO */
public class WorkerVO {

    private String workerAddress;
    public String getWorkerAddress() { 
       return workerAddress; 
    }
    public void setWorkerAddress(String workerAddress) {
       this.workerAddress = workerAddress;
    }

}

/* ActionScript VO */
[RemoteClass(alias="path.to.WorkerVO")]
public class WorkerVO {

    public var workerAddress:String;

}
```

This is an example with a Java VO, but the same applies to ColdFusion.

Comment: RIA star, thank you for all the effort you put in, this is the first time that Ive used flex, cold fusion and action script 3 and I see your name everywhere when im researching how things work.. Your time and comments and help is really appreciated. Im looking into building my server side code correctly in coldfusion i.e. value object cfcs I simply had database queries into cfset (very noob) =D might have another question or two but ill give it ago myself first.

Comment: @Cavej03 Just noticed that I forgot the `alias=` part in the RemoteClass metadata tags of my examples. Just edited my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the returned object to a property within `WorkerVO`, and prepare getters for each of them like so:

```
public class WorkerVO
{

    private var _base:Object;


    public function WorkerVO(base:Object)
    {
        _base = base;
    }


    public function get address():String{ return _base.workerAddress; }
    public function get city():String{ return _base.workerCity; }
    // Etc.

}
```

And the definition of a worker just needs the `new` keyword added:

```
var worker:WorkerVO = new WorkerVO(result[0]);
trace(worker.address);
```